# Converting a thesis.tex file that contains chapters into Word

Tags: biber, pandoc

I'm writing my thesis and I've separated it into a main .tex file and a set of chapters. I've structured it like so:

```
% Comment these sections out when compiling the whole thing:
%\includeonly{Chapter1/Chapter1}
%\includeonly{Chapter2/Chapter2}
%\includeonly{Chapter3/Chapter3}
%\includeonly{Chapter4/Chapter4}
%\includeonly{Chapter5/Chapter5}
%\includeonly{Chapter6/Chapter6}
%\includeonly{Chapter7/Chapter7}

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{thesisPSnPDF} 

% Note that I am using my own custom style for the bibliography that uses \cites commands (I'll come to the issues with that later...)

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=custom_style]{biblatex}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
  \def\@maketitle{%
 \begin{center}%
 \let \footnote \thanks
   {\textbf{\MakeUppercase\@title}}%
   \vskip 1em%
   {\textsc\@author}
 \end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\include{Title/Title}

\frontmatter
\include{Declaration/Declaration}
\include{Abstract/Abstract}

\include{Chapter1/Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3/Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4/Chapter4}
\include{Chapter5/Chapter5} 
\include{Chapter6/Chapter6}     
\include{Chapter7/Chapter7}
```

What I want to do is uncomment each of the \includeonly{Chapter{X}/Chapter{X}} statements, compile the chapter into a PDF and send it to my advisor for review. However, my advisor is pretty set on using Word and I would rather gnaw one of my own legs off than use Word, so I'm looking for a way to convert the separate PDF/chapter into its own chapter. I've tried pandoc but I run into issues with the following error:

```
 pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\x2c': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

I've looked up the utf-8 code and I know it's for a comma, so I've tried with one of my chapters and removed all of the commas to find this error but I'm still running into issues. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might achieve what I am attempting to do? For what it is worth I am using TexShop on Sierra. Thanks.

Comment: you can try `tex4ht`. it can convert TeX file to `ODT` format, which can be converted to Word using LibreOffice. Try `mk4ht oolatex filename.tex`

Comment: I've tried mk4ht oolatex but unfortunately the odt file that is returned is corrupted.

Comment: does it generate any compile errors?

Comment: I get lot of compilation errors with your sample even with pdflatex, but `oolatex` can generate valid file. There may be some issue in some file you include.

Comment: For what it's worth I used an Mac OS X app called SimpleTeX4ht that seems to convert the tex files to odt just fine. This is probably the best solution I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you working on Mac OS X, I've found the easiest solution is to use SimpleTeX4ht (http://www.simpletex4ht.free.fr/), which converts tex files into ODF. From there I can save these files as .doc files using LibreOffice. Not sure about non Mac OS X platforms, but I will give it a shot.